# rub image in canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am using android 2.x and I have four bitmaps drawn on a canvas, now i want to replace "yahoo" image with some other image and that image's size is different than "yahoo" image. Now what i want is , i want to rub the yahoo image and replace it with the new one but in such a way that if i rub "yahoo" image then images that are laying in the background don't get disturbed or vanished.

**here is the sample image**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds pretty simple to do....

on your ondraw function, you should just re-draw each bitmap, starting at the most bottom one to the top.

I dont know what do you mean by "rub", the only way I know how to do this is just to always re-draw each objects, and if you dont want Yahoo to show, just replace Yahoo bitmap with the new Bitmap that you wish to replace it.

Comment: well what if my next bitmap image is smaller then yahoo image. in that case my yahoo image will appear in background if i draw new bitmap on it . so basically i want remove yahoo and then want to load another.

Comment: for every refresh, everything will have to be re-drawn. If you dont want Yahoo to appear, just make sure dont draw Yahoo.

Comment: But i just want to redraw that advertisement part i.e. Yahoo part and want to put another advertise after few interval.. i dont want to redraw the whole canvas.